# TabBar Controller Selection color before IOS 5.0

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uicolor

I don't like the default color when  a tabbar item being selected ,and I know in IOS 5.0
I can implement it with one code :

```
self.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [UIColor thecolorIlike];
```

I would like  to know is there  anyway to implement it before IOS 5.0 .
Thanks a lot.